# Tomcat taking disk space while running

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, process, diskspace

I am facing a weird scenrio:
my tomcat7 is up, running my webapp (WAR) file for a couple of days.

After 2 days, my disk space is soo low, and after killing the TC process the disk space is being replenished (it takes a couple of GB while it runs).

How is it possible? (I think in 'top' i could see the VIRT with a tons of GB for the TC process)